# How can I turn off automatic start up of tomcat8 on windows

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat

I've running Apache Tomcat Server 7.0.56 on Windows 8.1. Whenever I start Windows up, I see `tomcat8.exe` listed as a process in the Task Manager window.

I would definitely like to turn off this automatic startup and only start it up manually when desired. I don't find it in the "Services" tab so am assuming it's not installed as a service.

I went to https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services and there are example commands in the "Updating services" section referencing the parameter `Startup=auto` but these are only if apache is installed as a service, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tomcat is running on your Windows computer without you starting it, it's running as a service. The service however is not necessarily named "Tomcat" though - it can be "My amazing application". Maybe accessing whatever application is running (`http://localhost:8080`?) gives you a hint for which sevice you should look.

You can also change the ports that your tomcat7 runs on in its conf/server.xml. Watch out for 8005, 8009 and 8080 if you want to change the default ports. You'll most likely need to change all of them - then you can access your tomcat 7 on the new port (after you save server.xml and start tomcat7) - both can exist peacefully in parallel

Comment: You're right. I found out it's actually Confluence that owns `tomcat8`, which confused me since I had installed Apache server for another project. Anyway, by uninstalling Confluence I was able to get rid of `tomcat8`.